# How can I post (one tweet) to twitter in php?

Tags: php, sql, twitter

Im using abrahams oauth twitter library. but Im having some difficulty posting to twitter from php on my site.

I am receiving zero errors, but nothing is happening.  Has anyone been able to solve this very simple issue?  Can you share you knowledge?

Thx

```
/* Load required lib files. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php'); 
require_once('twitteroauth/config.php');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth ('myprivatecode', myprivatecode', 'myprivatecode','myprivatecode'); 

$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $myTweet));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?PHP
require_once 'twitteroauth.php';

define("CONSUMER_KEY", "....");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET", "...");
define("OAUTH_TOKEN", "...");
define("OAUTH_SECRET", "...");

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET);
$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');

$connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'test'));

?>
```

After requesting Read & Write permissions, you have to RECREATE your access tokens to reflect the new permissions.

A working example for [Post to twitter using PHP Oauth API](http://www.walkswithme.net/post-to-twitter-using-php-oauth-api)

Hope it helps..

Comment: nailed it!  Thanks, the link was helpful too

Answer (score 0):

```
" /* Load required lib files. */ session_start(); 
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php'); require_once('twitteroauth/config.php');

$connection = new TwitterOAuth ('myprivatecode', myprivatecode' 'myprivatecode','myprivatecode');

$content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials'); $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $myTweet)); "
```

Have you set a variable via a form post or anything for

```
$mytweet
```

Without any more information it is hard to tell. I assume the files are correct in the require_once since the file actually processes.

Make sure the form is sent via post, not much else we can help with with so little information.